# Why is $\exp(\frac{1}{x^2})\geq \frac{1}{(2n)!x^{4n}}$?

Tags: analysis

From the Maclaurin series, I know that

$$\exp(\frac{1}{x^2}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n! x^{2n}}.$$

Can't see where this bound comes from. It's used in the last step of [this proof](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/category/analysis/).

Comment: Because every even $k$ is a term in the infinite series(, which with every terms greater than $0$)?

Comment: Oh yeah, I hadn't thought about the LHS being an even term